# can not use the list iterator in c++

Tags: c++, list, iterator

ok so i have errors in my code where i include an iterator.
here is the buggy part of my code:

```
for(list<char>::iterator it = eatUpRight.begin();it!= eatUpRight.end();it+=2)
{
    board[*it][*(it+1)]=3;
    _3eat2(*it,*(it+1),eatOptions,newCurrentEatingOption);
    board[*it][*(it+1)]=0;
}
```

don't worry about the board and _3eat2 and any other identifier because that is defentlly not the problem.
all you need to know is that board is a 2d array.

```
board[*it][*(it+1)]
```

the (it) is supose to be the index of the 2d array,but it gives me errors instead.
and gives me other errors on everywhere else that i try to use the iterator.
so can you please tell me whats wrong with this code?

Comment: Your code says you have a list of characters whose integer equivalents represent the indices of a 2D array.

Comment: You cannot use + on list iterators because they are not random access iterators.

Comment: Instead use `std::advance`, but seriously think about what's happening.

Answer (score 6):

`it + 1` is only valid for `RandomAccessIterators`. `list` doesn't provide `RandomAccessIterators`, but BidirectionalIterators. See an overview of the iterator library [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). Use [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance), to abstract away the difference of those operations.

Comment: If you're using c++11, you can also use `std::next` and `std::prev`, which might be easier to utilize in some cases.  They provide a wrapper around `std::advance`, but return the advanced iterator instead of modifying by reference.

Comment: @DaveS They also avoid the undefined behavior that `int arr[3]; --end(arr);` causes. Definitely the way to go, especially since they can also take a size, which makes them a lot more readable than `advance`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::list<T>::iterator
```

is a `bidirectional iterator`. It has no `operator +(std::ptrdiff_t)`; use `std::advance` instead of `operator +`

Answer (score 0):

Additional remark: `it` is not an index but an iterator. Amoong other things that means that you cannot use it on a different collection than the one that gave it to you.

You are receiving it from `eatUpRight` and are using it (as an index!) with `board`.